# Pinescript:possible to modify existing strategy.position_size or strategy.position_avg_price for DCA?

Tags: pine-script

I am doing calculations inside pine to know how quickly I can exit a position by applying DCA. This is all saved in local variables and I have my way of assuming from list of trades column. But is there any way I can modify strategy.position_avg_price parameter whenever my position falls to certain negative point so that I can increase position_size of already exiting open position so that it exits as a positive trade in "list of trades" column? I know these are built in variable but is there any indirect ways to modify their values?

Answer (score 0):

`strategy.position_avg_price` built-in variable represent the current average active position size, you can't directly modify it as it is read-only.

The only way to modify it's value is to execute a new `strategy.exit` / `strategy.entry` order and the value of `strategy.position_avg_price` will be recalculated accordingly.